# Current Date Token in Drupal View

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm  looking to create a Math expression in a View in Drupal 7 using the current date as a variable. I haven't found any simple token or way of referencing the current date within a math expression in views.

Does anyone know of an effective way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking for this as well. This is what I just threw together.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_views_api()
 */
function mymodule_views_api() {
  return array("version" => "3.0");
}

/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter()
 */
function mymodule_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  $data['views']['nothing_token'] = array(
    'title' => t('Custom text with token replacement'),
    'help' => t('Provide custom text or link with token replacement.'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_custom_token',
    ),
  );
}

class views_handler_field_custom_token extends views_handler_field_custom {
  function query() {
    // do nothing -- to override the parent query.
  }

  function render($values) {
    global $user;

    $data = array(
      'user' => $user,
      'view' => $this->view,
    );
    // Return the text, so the code never thinks the value is empty.
    return token_replace($this->options['alter']['text'], $data);
  }
}
```

Then in your view you would add the "Global: custom text with token replacement" field and use [current-date:raw] in the text field. You could then add a math expression using that field. You might be able to extend the views_handler_field_math class to do the same thing there, but haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I like Jonathan's approach of allowing tokens in custom text fields. Didn't quite work for me though because the render() function isn't what was outputting the value for me. I had to use the render_text function instead. This worked for me for the class. It's a little less destructive of the core views behavior as well.

```
class views_handler_field_custom_token extends views_handler_field_custom {
  function render($values) {
    global $user;

    $data = array(
      'user' => $user,
      'view' => $this->view,
    );
    // Return the text, so the code never thinks the value is empty.
    return token_replace(parent::render($values), $data);
  }

  function render_text($alter) {
    global $user;

    $data = array(
      'user' => $user,
      'view' => $this->view,
    );

    return token_replace(parent::render_text($alter), $data);
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to know how to use the current date in a token, see this list of available formats:

https://drupaltokens.com/tokens/current-date